# Bind select options to global variable/array?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, typescript

Suppose I have the following Javascript:

```
var Option = (function ()
{
        function Option(value, text)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.text = text;
        }

        return Option;
})();

var QuestionTypes = (function ()
{
    QuestionTypes.chooseOne = new Option("ChooseOne", "Choose One");
    QuestionTypes.chooseMany = new Option("ChooseMany", "Choose Many");
    QuestionTypes.text = new Option("Text", "Text");
    QuestionTypes.all = function ()
    {
        return
        [
            QuestionTypes.chooseOne, 
            QuestionTypes.chooseMany, 
            QuestionTypes.text
        ];
    };

    return QuestionTypes;
})();
```

And this HTML:

```
<select data-bind="value: type, options: QuestionTypes.all, optionsValue: value, optionsText: text" />
```

So the `select` is bound to my "static" variable `QuestionTypes`. I expect the resulting `select` to look something like this:

```
<select data-bind="value: type, options: QuestionTypes.all, optionsValue: value, optionsText: text">
    <option value="ChooseOne">Choose One</option>
    <option value="ChooseMany">Choose Many</option>
    <option value="Text">Text</option>
</select>
```

Basically, how do I bind to something that is global and NOT on the model itself?

Comment: FYI - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Option - did you know there's already a built-in constructor `new Option()`?

Comment: @Ian - yes, thanks - this class didn't start out as a true option but has turned into one...will probably switch to the built-in class as you suggested.

Comment: @gaurav - I know I can just add `var questionTypes = QuestionTypes.all;` to my model and reference it that way, just curious if there was a way to reference a global variable w/out doing it that way. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshM. I just wanted to point out there's already an object called `Option` - so I would assume you're overwriting it (not the best idea). So yeah, either adopt the use of it, or change the name of yours so they don't conflict so you can continue using it properly.

Comment: @Ian - agreed. I'm using Typescript and it doesn't seem to like the `Option` class but I'll get it working.

Comment: @Ian - FYI you have to create the option as `new Option(...)` if you want to pass parameters. But the actual type is `HTMLOptionElement`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind to global variables just fine. They are available in bindings just like anywhere else.

The problem in your example is that `optionsValue` and `optionsText` need to be strings.

```
options: QuestionTypes.all, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'text'
```